# How to click on a button in an app from the status bar with Apple Script

Tags: applescript

[image]

I have see how to click on menu items but this application does not have those. I was wondering how to click on the button Connect

I tried `click at {818, 320}` but it did not work

Here is the scrip, i was able to open the app with this

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell UI element "Hotspot Shield"
        tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            click
            delay 2
            get the actions of button "Connect"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW One would not normally use `tell UI element "Hotspot Shield"` rather use `tell application process "Hotspot Shield"`, however, looking at this through **Accessibility Inspector**, I do not see a way to click the "**Connect**" button. Even using a **Watch Me Do** *action* in **Automator**, while it will record the process, it won't play it back successfully.

That said, here is a workaround solution that works for me on **macOS Mojave** using **AppleScript** and the third-party command line utility [**Cliclick**](https://www.bluem.net/en/projects/cliclick/).

Looking at the cropped screen shot in your OP and using the approximate center of the **Connect** button to be at `320` for the `y` *axis* and using **AppleScript** to get the `position` of the `menu bar item` for use as the approximate `x` *axis*, the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* should work for you too.

```
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell application process "Hotspot Shield" to ¬
        tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
            set xPos to first item of (get its position)
            click
        end tell

delay 0.5

do shell script "/Applications/cliclick c:" & xPos & ",320"
```

- Note that the *value* of the `delay` *command* may need to be adjusted to ensure the **Connect** button is visible before the *click event* takes place using `cliclick`.
- Adjust the *path* to `cliclick` as needed. I placed it in `/Applications` just for testing purposes.
- The usual caveats, regarding **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy**, apply.
- I am not affiliated with the developer of Cliclick, just a satisfied user of the product.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error* handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>